# Displaying notification count in CodaNameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I am facing issues in displaying notification count against an icon. It should be displayed at right top corner.

First created button with padding and margin as zero and set the image to button.

```
FlowLayout buttonLayout = new FlowLayout();
buttonLayout.setAlign(Component.CENTER);
buttonLayout.setValign(Component.TOP);
Container buttonContainer = new Container(buttonLayout);
buttonContainer.setUIID("IconContainer");
Button button = new Button(buttonImage);
button.setUIID("ButtonLabelNew");
buttonContainer.addComponent(button);
```

The created a notification count container and laid it over button

```
FlowLayout countLayout = new FlowLayout();
countLayout.setAlign(Component.RIGHT);
countLayout.setValign(Component.TOP);
Container countContainer = new Container(countLayout);
Label countLabel = new Label(displayCount);
countLabel.setUIID("backgroundLabel");
countContainer.addComponent(countLabel);

/*Adding Button and Notification Count to ItemContainer*/
Container itemContainer = new Container(new LayeredLayout());
itemContainer.addComponent(buttonContainer);
itemContainer.addComponent(countContainer);
```

Now added the text below the button

```
BoxLayout iconLayout = new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
Container iconContainer = new Container(iconLayout);
Label iconText= new Label(buttonText);
iconText.setUIID("Label");
iconContainer.addComponent(0,itemContainer);
iconContainer.addComponent(1,iconText);
```

FInally created a grid and added icon containers to the grid

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(numRows, MAX_ITEMS_PER_ROW);
Container gridContainer = new Container(gridLayout);
gridContainer.setUIID("LogoContainer");
for (int indx = 0; indx < itemContainers.length; indx++) 
{
    gridContainer.addComponent(itemContainers[indx]);
}
approvalsWorklist.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,gridContainer);
```

Comment: What's not working here? This seems to be correct for the most part. Can you provide a screenshot of what you are getting and explain why its different from your desired end result?

Comment: Shai I posted the image here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wep74gq4oxoe60/grid.png)

Comment: The problem is the notification count doesnt appear at the exact right hand corner. There is a margin here.

Comment: The FlowLayout will put it where it sees fit. You should find out the area in which the FlowLayout is active, maybe it doesn't cover the whole area?

Answer (score 0):

The image is positioned at the right hand side but the component is larger than the icon so you see the image positioned where the components are sized.

There are two ways to solve this for you.

1. Set a padding or margin on `countContainer` so the count will be spaced and placed in the right location. This has the drawback of having to tune based on a uniform icon size which might not be the case but its a relatively simple approach.
2. I'm assuming the components are placed in a `GridLayout` which means they all have the exact same size. You will wrap each element in the grid layout in a `FlowLayout` or a an absolute center `BorderLayout` they will take up their preferred size internally and then the badge will be positioned exactly within the icon edge.

Comment: I did try these ways but it didnt work. In the end I changed the way grid is used. Instead of combining the icon and text below that to use in grid, I used grid with one row of icons and next row of related text.